# Where is the Fallout: New Vegas save game location?

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

I just reloaded Steam on a new computer and I can't find the folder to put my saved games into. Where is it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fallout: New Vegas stores saved game information in:

**My Documents/My Games/FalloutNV**

Answer (score 2):

Save File / Save Game Location:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\FalloutNV\Saves`
- Steam Play Linux: `<Steam-folder>/steamapps/compatdata/22380/pfx/`

To find the Path:

- Open the File Explore
- Paste `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\FalloutNV\Saves`
- Press Enter

Configuration Files Location:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\FalloutNV\FalloutPrefs.ini`
- Steam Play Linux: `<Steam-folder>/steamapps/compatdata/22380/pfx/`

Source: [Filelocations](https://www.filelocations.com/fallout-new-vegas-save-file-location/)